# You can create class object only using second class (first class doesn't have constructor?)

Tags: c#, class, constructor

Example from ScriptHookDotNet:

First class:

```
public sealed class Vehicle : GTA.base.HandleObject
//Member of GTA

public abstract class HandleObject : GTA.base.Object
//Member of GTA.base

public abstract class Object
//Member of GTA.base
```

Second class:

```
public sealed class World
//Member of GTA
```

Method used:

```
public static GTA.Vehicle CreateVehicle(GTA.Vector3 Position)
```

You can't create object from Vehicle just using:

```
Vehicle veh = new Vehicle();
```

Because Vehicle doesn't have constructor.

But you can using this code:

```
Vehicle veh = World.CreateVehicle(params);
```

How it's made?

Comment: See [this FAQ on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/156418) for tips on formatting your code.

Comment: Can you show some of the code from `World.CreateVehicle`?

Answer (score 8):

The constructor is private, so they force you to use the specific method to create an instance. This is known as a Factory pattern; internally to the World class, that method has the capacity to create a new instance of the `Vehicle` with the constructor, but you cannot.

EDIT: If you want to create this kind of functionality, then you would do something like this:

```
public class MyPublicClass
{
    public MyPrivateClass CreateClass()
    {
         return MyPrivateClass.GetInstance();
    }
}

public class MyPrivateClass
{
    internal static MyPrivateClass GetInstance() { return new MyPrivateClass(); }        

    protected MyPrivateClass() { }
}
```

Comment: I suspected it was something like this, but then it sounded like he had created this code himself. +1 for reading between the lines.

Comment: How can I use private constructor from other class without using internal? Is it possible? Can you post some example how it's looking from inside?

Comment: @damned - I would assume the constructor is actually internal rather than private. It's also possible that `Vehicle` has an internal factory method that `World.CreateVehicle` is accessing.

Comment: I agree. The constructor is probably `internal`. However, you should theoretically be able to create a new instance via Reflection, but that's kinda getting into grey territory. If you need to create a vehicle, you should probably use the factory method.

Comment: No no, this is example what I try to copy to my code. I want class 1 can be only created by class 2 method but I don't know how code should look.

Comment: You should only expose a static factory method then; I'll update my answer with a sample.

Comment: It's working but I also can just use **MyPrivateClass mc = MyPrivateClass.GetInstance()**. I think this is made using C++ and friend (this example from ScriptHook).

Comment: If you package this into a DLL and include it in another program, that other program will not be able to call `MyPrivateClass.GetInstance()`

Comment: Point for you! It's works as I wanted. Can you tell me why this working after compile to DLL?

Comment: `internal` means `public` inside the same DLL. Outside of the DLL, it means `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Additional comment: If you can modify the code, you may want to add a custom public constructor to your classes.

Think different ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the Vehicle class is anything but public (protected, internal, private) by design, because the class creators wanted to have finer control over how the objects were created.

In addition to the Factory pattern already mentioned, the singleton pattern also uses this method of class creation to ensure that only one instance of a particular class is created (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html).

I have also seen this pattern used by the Event Aggregator(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx) class that needs knowledge about the events you want to publish or subscribe to, which seems to be the case here. For example, if you simply instantiated a Vehicle class, how would the World class know to put that vehicle into the scene or to use that vehicle object when interacting with other objects? Instead of designing some method to add the vehicle to the world (i.e. worldInstance.AddVehicle(..) I think in this case World was designed to control how objects interacting with the World are created.

For more information on the Factory pattern see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx